# Unit test suspend function coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a repository that looks like below

```
interface DataSource {
    suspend fun getStatus(id: String): StateFlow<Status>
}
class repository(
    val dataSource: DataSource,
    val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) {
    val map: ConcurrentMap<String, StateFlow<Status>> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    fun getStatus(id: String): StateFlow<Status> {
        return map.getOrPut(id) {
            openChannel(id)
            MutableStateFlow(DEFAULT_VALUE)
        }
    }
    
    private fun openChannel(id: String) {
        coroutineScope.launch { 
            observeDataSource(id)
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun observeDataSource(id: String) {
       dataSource.getStatus(id)
            .collect {
                map[id]?.update {it}
            }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for it like below

```
private lateinit var repository: Repository
private val dataSource: DataSource = mockk()

@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    repository = Repository(
        dataSource = dataSource,
        coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()),
    )
}

@Test
fun `test getStatus`() =
    runTest {
        val expectedStatus = createExpectedStatus()
        coEvery { dataSource.getStatus(any()) } returns flowOf(
            expectedExteriorStatus
        )
        var result: Status? = null
        backgroundScope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)) {
            repository.getStatus("id").collect {
                result = it
            }
        }

        assertEquals(
            expectedStatus,
            result
        )
    }
```

The `result` is always `DEFAULT_VALUE` and not `expectedStatus` even though the `result` is received at some point. This works fine in real application, but just fails in unit test. I suspect it has something to do with the `UnconfinedTestDispatcher`. Any idea how this could be fixed?